# T-SQL split response header from SP

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, split

Within a T-SQL script I am calling a stored procedure, this stored procedure handles HTTP requests and is returning stuff like HTTP status code, status text and response headers.

The stored procedure is an 3rd party managed/created SP which I cannot edit (because when the vendor is updating their application the SP will be overwritten). So I have to deal with the output of the SP.

The response header which I am receiving after the HTTP call is made is a full string of all the headers (seperated by two spaces '  ').

This is the response header:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store,max-age=0  Connection: keep-alive  Date: Thu, 10 Feb 2022 07:46:23 GMT  Transfer-Encoding: chunked  Via: 1.1 <snip>.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)  Content-Type: application/json  Notification-Box-Id: 627ac06d-snip-snip-snip-7ae2cda3f8ae  Notification-Message-Id: c6ef44cd-snip-snip-snip-be196a48751b  X-Envoy-Upstream-Service-Time: 105  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;  Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload  X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront  X-Amz-Cf-Pop: FRA6-C1  X-Amz-Cf-Id: 61b-snip-snipsnipsnip-vpg==
```

I need to have the value of two response headers (Notification-Box-Id & Notification-Message-Id) from this string. I've tried to use STRING_SPLIT but it does not accept two spaces (because of nchar(1)).

My assumption is that the format is always the same, so with LEFT(), RIGHT() and LEN() I can probably manage it to work. But is this the way to go? Is there any other option which is less messy?

Comment: Honestly, don't do this is T-SQL, it's terrible at such things like string manipulation. Do this in your application layer. If you "must" do it in SQL Server, use CLR objects. I don't doubt there are C# libraries out there that can parse such header, for example.

Comment: Just write your own string split function that accepts multiple characters.

Comment: "this stored procedure handles HTTP requests" bad idea. T-SQL is not a generalized scripting language, don't use it as such. C# and Python are far better at this kind of thing

Comment: You can just `REPLACE` the two spaces with `|` or something

Comment: I understand your recommendations about using C#/Python etc. but this is a legacy application which is mainly used by a customer. I have to deal with the current situation without re-building stuff.

The REPLACE function is not working with two spaces, only with one. Currently writing own SPLIT function for this particular thing.

Comment: String splitting is the MOST COMMON question on SO. Simple searching will find many examples of custom splitting logic. Search first. No one can answer "is this the right way" since no one has any context, but real life does not always lead to "beautiful" code.

Comment: *"I have to deal with the current situation without re-building stuff."* you're going to have to build *something*, you can't have your existing code automagically do something it isn't already without changing it.

Comment: Replacing the spaces with a single character, then splitting, is workable, if quite brittle -- because there's no rule that says HTTP headers can't contain spaces. Are you sure those are *actually* spaces, and not just the way (say) Management Studio is displaying newlines (`CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)`)? You can convert to a `VARBINARY(MAX)` to check.

Comment: You don't really even need a string splitting function for this, CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING are more than sufficient, and the performance overhead is really not a problem 99% of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite easy. Grab a copy of [delimitedSplit8k](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function). It returns the item and it's ordinal position in the string. And it's fast.

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(1000) = 'Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store,max-age=0  Connection: keep-alive  Date: Thu, 10 Feb 2022 07:46:23 GMT  Transfer-Encoding: chunked  Via: 1.1 <snip>.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)  Content-Type: application/json  Notification-Box-Id: 627ac06d-snip-snip-snip-7ae2cda3f8ae  Notification-Message-Id: c6ef44cd-snip-snip-snip-be196a48751b  X-Envoy-Upstream-Service-Time: 105  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;  Content-Security-Policy: default-src ''self''  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload  X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront  X-Amz-Cf-Pop: FRA6-C1  X-Amz-Cf-Id: 61b-snip-snipsnipsnip-vpg==    ';

SELECT split.*
FROM
(
  SELECT split.Item, Val = LEAD(split.Item,1) OVER (ORDER BY split.ItemNumber)
  FROM DW.dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@x, '') AS split
) AS split(Item,ItemValue)
WHERE split.Item LIKE '%Notification-Box-Id%'
 OR   split.Item LIKE '%Notification-Message-Id%';
```

**Returns:**

```
Item                      ItemValue
------------------------- -----------------------------------------
Notification-Box-Id:      627ac06d-snip-snip-snip-7ae2cda3f8ae
Notification-Message-Id:  c6ef44cd-snip-snip-snip-be196a48751b
```